# How to define github 2 in codepipeline through cloudformation template

Tags: github, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am using a cloudformation template to create a codepipeline. In codepipeline I wanted to Github2 in the source but I couldnt find any reference in AWS documentation to do so.

The following is a github 1  which works but I wanted to use github2

```
CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      Name: forexViewPipeline
    Stages:
      - Name: Source
        Actions:
          - Name: SourceAction
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Source
              Owner: ThirdParty
              Version: 1
              Provider: GitHub
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. CodeStar Connection Resource

A connection definition in the CloudFormation stack needs to be created in order to be used in the pipeline.  Since CloudFormation does not know your GitHub credentials, this connection will be created in the `Pending` status until you navigate to Pipelines > Settings > Connections ([This URL](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/settings/connections) for us-east-1) and finish setting up the connection.

```
  GithubConnection:
    Type: AWS::CodeStarConnections::Connection
    Properties:
      ConnectionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-GithubConnection
      ProviderType: GitHub
```

### 2. CodePipeline Source Stage

Now that we have the connection defined as a resource, we can use that as the initial source stage in our pipeline. In the below example, I am setting the github owner/repo/branch via Parameters on the stack.  Note that the output artifact of the source stage needs to match the input artifact of the following stage:

```
Parameters:
  GithubBranch:
    AllowedPattern: ".+"
    Type: String
    Description: "Github branch name e.g. development"
    Default: "main"
  GithubOwner:
    AllowedPattern: ".+"
    Type: String
    Description: "Github repo owner"
  GithubRepo:
    AllowedPattern: ".+"
    Type: String
    Description: "Github repo name"

...
  PipelineBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  CodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CodePipeline
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipeLineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref PipelineBucket
        Type: S3
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Github
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
                Version: "1"
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: MySourceCode
              Configuration:
                ConnectionArn: !Ref GithubConnection
                FullRepositoryId: !Sub "${GithubOwner}/${GithubRepo}"
                BranchName: !Ref GithubBranch
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: Build
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: "1"
                Provider: CodeBuild
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: MySourceCode
...
```

### 3. Pipeline Role IAM Access to CodeStar Connection

The pipeline IAM role resource needs access to the connection:

```
  CodePipeLineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: S3CodebuildAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                  - s3:GetBucketVersioning
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn
                  - !Sub ${PipelineBucket.Arn}/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codebuild:BatchGetBuilds
                  - codebuild:StartBuild
                Resource:
                  - "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codestar-connections:UseConnection
                Resource:
                  - !Ref GithubConnection
```

### 4. Finish authorizing connection

As mentioned in step 1, once you are complete with the creation of the stack, you will need to navigate to *CodePipeline > Settings > Connections* and find the connection you created in the `Pending` status.  Open the connection and finish establishing the connection details.

Once the connection is established, it will begin triggering the pipeline on new pushes to the branch.

Documentation:

- [CodeStar Resource Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codestarconnections-connection.html)
- [CodeStar Connection definitions in CodePipeline stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only things I had to change were the ConnectionName which has a limit of 32 characters which when combined with the pipeline name was exceeeded. I also had to add default strings for the Githubowner and GithubRepo.

I'm unsure if this is needed too as I was shoehorning this into an existing setup with the roles already setup but I had to add these two permissions too.

- 'codestar-connections:CreateConnection'
- 'codestar-connections:PassConnection'

Leaving this in case it helps others.